# Laravel, Eloquent: how to access model instances? (I dont want static calls)

Tags: php, laravel

given some code:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Reception extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'receptions';

    /**
     * get all with repetitive info
     */
    public function getAllWithRepetitiveInfo() : Collection
    {
        return DB::table('receptions')->leftJoin('receptions_repetitives', 'receptions_repetitives.reception_id', '=', 'receptions.id')->get();
    }
}
```

this `getAllWithRepetitiveInfo` would be used somewhere in my controller, but... how? Seeing the documentations: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent all I see were static calls. I dont want that...
here https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices I saw something similar:

public function index()
{
return view('index', ['clients' => **$this->client**->getWithNewOrders()]);
}

but of course following this logic: `$this->reception` won't work (property doesn't exist) and I dont know how it would even be injected.

So all in all, I want to avoid `Reception::getAllWithRepetitiveInfo()`, I want to do `$this->reception->getAllWithRepetitiveInfo()`

Comment: I think in the model file, you can use `static::leftJoin`

Comment: I just doubt  if it's good to put your code in the model file.

Comment: but I cant go to controller either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inject your model as dependency (in constructor or method or other) then you can call it like that you want:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(private Reception $reception) {}

    public function index() {
      dd($this->reception->getAllWithRepetitiveInfo());
    }

}
```

Comment: oh, very cool, thats what I was looking for. However, if I needed 10 models, 10 parameters of constructor would be fishy...

Comment: @JohnSmith it is PHP ... `$yourModel = new YourModel;` ... and that method is a perfectly fine candidate for a static method since it doesn't have anything to do with an instance of the Model ... also not sure why you are using Query builder in that method when you can do this through Eloquent since you are querying to the table of the Model

Comment: And what if its not the controller but an other class? Looks like it doesnt automatic inject